# Is there a consequence to being over data storage limit?

Tags: limits, data

Our organization is at about 170% of our data storage limit. Is there any consequences of this? Or will Salesforce just not care about the limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe If you do not get your storage use down to within the limit you will be contacted and asked to purchase additional storage and potentially you could be unable to perform any more DML until you are within the limits.

I am not sure of the tolerances and it is completely up to salesforce when they choose to enforce the limit.

Comment: There's a "soft" cap (100%) and a "hard" cap (was previously 110%, but I'm guessing that may have changed). The area between the two is "grace storage", meant to tide over an organization until they had time to notice (e.g. nagging emails) and react (e.g. get below limit, order space). Salesforce won't admit to the grace storage, nor how it's calculated, so orgs don't take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen bulk data loads fail when storage is > 100% - so if you are loading in data via Dataloader, you'll get an error...